# How To Reduce the Number of 404s flagged in Google Console

Tags: http-status-code-404

My client has received an email notification from Google Search Console showing there are hundreds of broken links on the website. I've reached out to the client, and the've let me know that they'd decided to change the URL taxonomy, so now all pages that used to have URL structure client.com/resources/keyword are moved to client.com/keyword.

What steps should the client and I take in order to solve the issue and reduce the number of 404s flagged in GSC?

I'm not a tech or wb expert so a detailed step by step answer could help me alot